# Agregar columna a select con valor incremental

Tags: mysql, select

Dispongo de una tabla con un campo referencia y otro elemento.
Cada referencia puede estar formada por uno o 2 elementos que aparecen en la misma tabla, por eso necesito mediante una consulta obtener la referencia el primer elemento (el cual siempre aparecerá) y el segundo elemento (en algunos casos no tiene):

```
REFERENCIA | CAMPO1 | CAMPO2
----------------------------
 Manuel    |   1    |   2   |
----------------------------
 Fran      |   1    |   3   |
----------------------------
 Fran      |   3    |   7   |
----------------------------
 Carlos    |   6    |   4   |
----------------------------
```

Me gustaría obtener en un consulta un campo añadido con un auto numérico para cada aparición de REFERENCIA, es decir para la primer aparición de Fran un campo añadido 1 en la primera aparición y en la segunda aparición un campo añadido 2.
Así luego mediante una condición podría dejar de mostrar todas las segundas apariciones de una Referencia

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: Con que fin intentas hacer esto, no mostrar referencias repetidas?

Comment: ¿Que resultado esperas? ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento, ya realizaste alguna investigación previa. Te dejo los siguientes enlaces para que mejores tu pregunta. Evita los negativos e incluso el cierre de tu pregunta. [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878). De paso Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: He editado la pregunta dando mas información

Comment: como diferencias el primero del segundo? cuales son los datos de entrada? que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: No hay forma de diferenciarlos por eso necesito unirlos con un left join, pero entonces me los duplica